# What is the fastest way to scan all ports of a single maching using tcp scan

Tags: networking, port, nmap, port-scanning

After reading this post [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80713/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scan-all-ports-of-a-single-machine), from security.stackexchange, I was wondering what is the best way to scan all ports of a single maching using tcp scan only.

"nmap -sT -p 1-65535 localhost" is what I would try naturally but, I suppose, there is a better solution.

Also, I think that tcp scan is fastest than udp scan. In his [reply](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80713/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scan-all-ports-of-a-single-machine#comment132599_80744) the OP from that link wrote that he reached 12k ports in less than 3 secs using udp scan on nmap but with no accuracy. Is really possible the same results but using tcp scan (12k ports in 3 secs or less) and having the certain that all ports were scanned? (using a tool like Nmap or not)

Comment: TCP scan doesn't find UDP ports, so if your goal is to find UDP ports (like that OP) the fact TCP scan is faster is totally useless and irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

The best reference for that would be Nmap's documentation https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html - here it clearly states that SYN is faster than CONNECT so the default of -sS should be faster than -sT. It also says that TCP scans are faster than UDP scans because of various issues such as message types, rate limiting, firewalls and others. What the OP says is possible; however, depending on system configuration, the results probably lack accuracy (although it might be doable in a fast network without any firewalls slowing down the business).